# How to add a binary file in a visual studio project

Tags: c++

I wish to include in my existing project a binary file that stores data. This file will be accessed by the program and its data can be analysized. I want to use a binary file because it will save memory space.

Can I add a binary file in my solution explorer, or should it go somewhere as?

Answer (score 1):

If you need this file in run time to read from and you want to open it using relative path like `std::ifstream("binaryfilename", std::ios_base::binary)`, then the easiest way is to set the working directory of your startup project to the folder where this file is located. You can access this by right clicking your startup project, choosing Properties, then go to Debugging and change the Working Directory. Note that properties are per configuration so you need to do this for both Debug and Release configurations if you want to run the corresponding configuration.